# when I define the template class static member, why doesn't it initialize until it appears in some implementations?

Tags: c++

H i, everyone.

I wrote a simple template Singleton class, like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& getInstance () {return ms_instance;}
    static T ms_instance;
};

template<typename T>
T Singleton<T>::ms_instance;
```

and I also wrote some subclass, such as:

```
class A
    : public Singleton<A>
{
public:
    A ()
    {
        cout << "xxx" << endl;
    }
};
```

What I want to do is calling A's ctor when I declear class A, but the above code doesn't work. I don't use A explictly elsewhere.

I found 2 ways to slove it. The first is explicitly defining A::ms_instance, and the second is simply code it in the Singleton's ctor, like the following:

```
...
Singleton ()
{
    ms_instance;
}
...
```

Now, I have 2 questions.

1. Why does the second way work?
2. If I have many subclass, what's the order of their initialization? In order to facilitate understanding, I'll give an example.

   ```
   class A
       : Singleton<A>
   {
   public:
       A () { cout << "A" << endl; }
   };

   class B
       : Singleton<B>
   {
   public:
       B () { cout << "B" << endl; }
   };

   class C
       : Singleton<C>
   {
   public:
       C () { cout << "C" << endl; }
   };
   ...
   //when the application runs, does it output ABC, CBA or indeterminacy?
   ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've met the same problem recently. It's just optimized away by the compiler, since it's never used. I'm going to find some good duplicates for you, which address the problem.

Comment: why do you inherit, when your `Singleton` already has a `ms_instance` member?

Comment: Also consider using Scott Meyer's Singleton idiom.

Comment: so it depends on compiles, and are not in the c++ specification?

Comment: @frankcrc Make something in your derived class uisng that singleton instance. E.g. define a dummy method in the base, and call that one in the derived class constructor.

Comment: @tobi303 I recently used that technique to self register some stuff with another (decoupled) interface.

Comment: @tobi303 if i don't do that, how can i declear other class?O.O

Comment: @frankcrc maybe I am just a bit confused, bit I would simply use `Singleton<A>` instead of `A : Singleton<A>`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ just like the second way i mentioned. I'm a little worry about whether it depends on compilers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks :)